# Torch.onnx.export of module used positional and keyword arguments

Tags: pytorch, export, onnx

I defined a simple nn.Module with forward(..) function using positional and keyword arguments:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

cuda0 = torch.device('cuda:0')
x = torch.tensor([[[[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.], [7., 8., 9.]]]]).to(device=cuda0)

class MyModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 1, 2)
        ).to(device=cuda0)

    def forward(self, cond, **kwargs):
        if (cond):
            return self.net(kwargs['input'])
        else:
            return torch.tensor(0).to(device=cuda0)

module = MyModule()
module(torch.tensor(True).to(device=cuda0), **{'input': x})
```

Next, I am trying to export this module to onnx:

```
torch.onnx.export(module,
                  args=(torch.tensor(True).to(device=cuda0), {'input': x}), 
                  f='sample.onnx', input_names=['input'], output_names=['output'], export_params=True)
```

But that leads to an error:

```
TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I suppose, I am doing that according to the documentation:

> All but the last element of the tuple will be passed as non-keyword
> arguments, and named arguments will be set from the last element.

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html

What I am doing wrong?

Pytorch 1.8.0

Comment: This error is also getting discussed in [this pytorch issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/110439).

Comment: @Seon thanks, It's my issue I have opened on Pytorch Github

Answer (score 0):

you may need to arrange your named arguments as dict contained in tuple like this:

args = (
x,
{
"y": input_y,
"z": input_z
}
)

ref: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx_torchscript.html#module-torch.onnx